# Is there any way to send a file trough an array via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, codeigniter

I filled up an array with a lot of information(80+variables) and 1 file.

```
var ArrayEnv= {LOTS OF VARIABLES DECLARED + 1 File}
console.log(ArrayEnv); -> Just for testing purposes

$.ajax({
   url: 'controller/send_data',
   data: ArrayEnv,
   type: 'POST',
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   before:  '',
   success: function(data) {
   console.log('Ajax Value: '+data);
}});
```

So, when I send the data to the controller without the FILE, everythin goes right, but whenever I send a file it crashes.
I dont want to use formData since im getting and validating multiple variables through branchings on the JS.

I've done a lot of research and im really losing hope...
is there any way to send a file in the same array that containts the data?

---

### Update:

Actually had to use formData to make it work

```
   data = new FormData($("#validatedForm")[0]);

   $.ajax({
       url: 'controller/send_data',
       data: data,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       beforeSend: function() {
         console.log('Load');
     },
       method: 'POST',
      // type: 'POST', // For jQuery < 1.9
       success: function ( data ) {
           console.log( data );
       }
   });
```

Comment: The only way to do that is... to use formData. I don't see how the reason you stated for not using it is a reason for not using it though. How does `getting and validating multiple variables` have anything to do with how you're then sending the variables to the server?

Comment: *whenever I send a file it crashes*: what file extension?, what file size? etc are we talking about.? Also "IT CRASHES" is a bit vague, please add the error message(s) you experience on client and/or server side

Comment: @Vickel 
Uncaught TypeError: 'slice' called on an object that does not implement interface Blob.

Comment: @ChrisG when sent via formData it takes raw data from the entire form, not caring if it follow certain rules asked for... right?

Comment: When you do `const fd = new FormData();` you can now put in there whatever you want. In your case you would append the file object and the rest of the data in the form of JSON (i.e. the stringified array)

Comment: please place your update as an self answer, in order to create a proper question/answer pair, thanks. See 
[**Can I answer my own question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: also read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/251777